# .NET System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient class doesn't issue QUIT command to SMTP transaction

Tags: .net, smtp

Has anybody had issues with this?  If so, how do you get around it?  We are getting sporadic timeout issues and this is getting blamed.

The same issue is reported here as well:

> http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?p=3609268

Comment: I'll also like to mention avoid Safabyte email components like the plague, not only is it fraudulent, but I've also experienced major issues using this 3rd party email suite.

Comment: Has this been fixed in newer .NET frameworks or not?

Comment: @jocull looks like this was fixed in 4.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if there's an easier way to work around this specific problem, but one option would be to download the source for Mono's SmtpClient and use that (modifying if necessary). Their version definitely does send a QUIT command.

One project that I work on required us to send large numbers of emails. .NET's implementation was too inefficient, not providing any way to send multiple distinct emails in the same SMTP session. We fell back on using Mono's implementation and modifying it to allow us to manually control when the QUIT command was sent and the connection closed. There were a total of 25 relevant Mono classes that we had to merge into our project for this (mostly copy+paste and edit namespace).

It seems a little extreme, but if there's no way to work around the issue, it may be your best 3rd-party alternative: it's free, it's not a great deal of work and its API is **almost** identical to the native SmtpClient's.

Comment: Just make sure, that you adhere to Mono license ( http://www.mono-project.com/Licensing ). The source code is under MIT X11 license, which basically means that you have to tell somewhere in the documentation that you are using part of mono and you also have to cite the license text in your documentation.

Comment: how would you go about doing this?

Comment: @JL - the SmtpClient.SendCore method does all the work: initialising everything, sending data then sending the QUIT command and closing the connection & streams. We basically moved the QUIT command and the closing of everything into a public Close method and called it manually as required. However, considering it now, I think implementing IDisposable and also automatically calling Dispose upon finalization would have been more elegant.

Comment: any chance of you making that mono modified DLL public?

Answer (score 4):

Is your application running on a machine with an IIS? If so, you could take advantage of the built-in SMTP Service by setting the delivery method of your SMTP client like this:

```
var client = new SmtpClient 
{ 
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis 
};
```

I am using this in a few applications, and it's very reliable.

Comment: We are required to use SMTP on a different server.

Comment: The SMTP service is a relay agent only - mails are forwarded to an SMTP server of your choice.

Comment: This means you have to configure and maintain the local SMTP server right?

Answer (score 4):

It is solved in .Net 4. They implemented IDispose and this sends the QUIT command and frees resources.

This is a copy of the relevant documentation on MSDN:

> The SmtpClient  class has no Finalize
>   method, so an application must call
>   Dispose  to explicitly free up
>   resources. The Dispose  method
>   iterates through all established
>   connections to the SMTP server
>   specified in the Host  property and
>   sends a QUIT message followed by
>   gracefully ending the TCP connection.
>   The Dispose  method also releases the
>   unmanaged resources used by the Socket
>   and optionally disposes of the managed
>   resources.
>
> Call Dispose when you are finished
>   using the SmtpClient. The Dispose
>   method leaves the SmtpClient in an
>   unusable state. After calling Dispose,
>   you must release all references to the
>   SmtpClient so the garbage collector
>   can reclaim the memory that the
>   SmtpClient was occupying.

Comment: -1 The SMTPClient in .net v4.0 RTM is unable to send attachments larger than 3-4MB's so using .net v4.0 RTM for mailing is not a solution!

Comment: It is a known bug and it will be fixed in the future. See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544562/cannot-send-e-mails-with-large-attachments-system-net-mail-smtpclient-system-net-mail-mailmessage

Comment: A public patch is now available for this issue. You can find it here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=30226

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm going to find a 3rd party product to fix the problem.  The mono solution sounds interesting, but I'd rather spend a few bucks and get a commercial solution.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: No, it's the answer as to how I'm going to get around the limitation.